# Webscraping/Table Issues

Tags: python, web-scraping, spyder

Edit to previous post: I converted the code over to BeautifulSoup as suggested (I think I did it right). I am getting an error now:

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U28'), dtype('float64')) -> None
```

Here is the converted code and what I'm trying to do after which also includes some things I have tried to fix it. (This is code not written by me but I am trying to experiment with it and complete a different project--code was pulled from Github).

```
 # Function to pull URLs of all NCAA basketball stat tables on teamrankings.com
def team_rankings_pull():
    tr_url = "https://www.teamrankings.com/ncb/stats/"
    response = requests.get(tr_url)
   
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        tables = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'tr-table datatable'})
        
        
        ncb_links = []
        np.dtype(ncb_links)
#        ncb_links=ncb_links.astype(np.float)
        for table in tables:
            stat_link = table.find('a', {'class': 'data-value'})['href']
            np.dtype(stat_link)
#            stat_link=stat_link.astype(np.float)
            ncb_links.append(stat_link)
#            ncb_links=ncb_links.astype(np.float)
            
       
        ncbdf = pd.DataFrame({"ncb_links": ncb_links})
        ncbdf["url"] = 'https://www.teamrankings.com' + ncbdf["ncb_links"]
        return ncbdf
    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve data. Status code: {response.status_code}")

# Uncomment the line below to run the function
team_ranking_index = team_rankings_pull()

# Function to pull a specific table from Team Rankings
def team_rankings_stat_pull(stat_to_pull, year):
    row_index = team_ranking_index[team_ranking_index["Stat Categories"]["Stats"] == stat_to_pull].index
    pulled_row = team_ranking_index.loc[row_index]
    the_url = f"{pulled_row['url'].values[0]}?date={year}-07-01"
    
    page = pd.read_html(the_url)
    stat_dataset = pd.concat(page)
    stat_dataset.replace("--", np.nan, inplace=True)
    
    # Convert columns to numeric
    numeric_columns = stat_dataset.columns[2:]
    stat_dataset[numeric_columns] = stat_dataset[numeric_columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
    
    # Replace team names with abbreviations
    stat_dataset = stat_dataset.apply(lambda x: logos.loc[logos["TeamRankingsName"] == x, "TEAM"].values[0] if x in logos["TeamRankingsName"].values else x)
    
    stat_dataset = stat_dataset.iloc[:, 1:]  # Remove the first column (Rank)
    
    return stat_dataset
```

Newer to Python and trying to run some code using Spyder within Anaconda. Getting the below error but not totally sure where it is coming from or what is causing it. Any help is much appreciated!

```
runfile('C:/Users/ksgri/OneDrive/Desktop/NCAA_Basketball/NCAA_Basketball_Code.py', wdir='C:/Users/ksgri/OneDrive/Desktop/NCAA_Basketball')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File c:\users\ksgri\onedrive\desktop\ncaa_basketball\ncaa_basketball_code.py:79
    team_ranking_index = team_rankings_pull()
  File c:\users\ksgri\onedrive\desktop\ncaa_basketball\ncaa_basketball_code.py:72 in team_rankings_pull
    tr = pd.read_html(tr_url)[0]
  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py:1212 in read_html
    return _parse(
  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py:1001 in _parse
    raise retained
  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py:981 in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py:257 in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py:613 in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")

ValueError: No tables found
```

I think its this specific code causing the error but I'm not exactly sure.

```
# Function to pull URLs of all NCAA basketball stat tables on teamrankings.com
def team_rankings_pull():
    tr_url = "https://www.teamrankings.com/ncb/stats/"
    tr = pd.read_html(tr_url)[0]
    ncb_links = tr["Stat Categories"]["Stats"]
    ncbdf = pd.DataFrame({"ncb_links": ncb_links})
    ncbdf["url"] = 'https://www.teamrankings.com' + ncbdf["ncb_links"]
    return ncbdf

# Uncomment the line below to run the function
team_ranking_index = team_rankings_pull()
```

Comment: After inspecting the element for the URL you provided, I do not see any HTML tables - only list item elements. Per Pandas' read_html documentation, it only supports searching for table elements.  Consider using something like BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML List Items into a Pandas Dataframe and go from there. Here's an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137612/extract-information-from-html-list-to-pandas-df-list-dict-python-3-0